# Can't use langdetect package in python

Tags: python

I am trying to detect language of the string with langdetect package. But it does not work.

```
from langdetect import detect

word_string = "Books are for reading"
print(detect(word_string))
```

If I use code above I get error `ImportError: cannot import name detect`

When I replace detect with *

```
from langdetect import *

word_string = "Books are for reading"
print(detect(word_string))
```

I get error: `NameError: name 'detect' is not defined`

So my question is how can I solve these problems ?

**So the problem was that my langdetect package and python file was with the same name.... Thank you for your answers.**

Comment: What's the output of `import langdetect` and then `langdetect.detect()`?

Comment: the output is "AttributeError: module 'langdetect' has no attribute 'detect'" 

I use https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect#basic-usage as a tutorial.

Comment: Then I'd say your `detect` function doesn't exist with that name...

Answer (score 4):

Try installing it first by writing :->
`!pip install langdetect` on terminal
and then `import langdetect`

Answer (score 1):

You can not import it because it is probably not there. See if the name is correct. Seeing other questions here on SO I assume you mean detect_langs.

Comment: I just installed it myself and you're correct with the use so maybe there's something wrong with your installation. What version of python and the package do you have installed? You can always try to uninstall it and install it again

Answer (score 1):

Your error indicates the Python interpreter couldn't find the `module` you are importing in it's `sys.path`.

Add to your code

```
import os
sys.path.append('absolute_path to your module.py file')
```

and try again. 
Another option is to add your **[PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)** environment variable the folder containing your module.

Try `import langdetect` after validating it's path is in your `sys.path` variable; if this commands succeeds it means you loaded the module successfully. Now you need to address the detect function as `langdetect.detect` because it resides in the `langdetect` namespace. If it doesn't find it - it's not there.